# Where I can take/configure/see a roleSessionName for configuring STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider for v1 or v2 credential provider AWS SDK?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to configure either **STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider** of **SDK V1** or
**StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider** of **SDK V2** to run requests against **S3**.

Both constructors need **String roleArn, String roleSessionName**. If role Arn can be taken from a specific IAM role but regarding sessionsName I don't have any thoughts(How it could configured/generated? Where can it be taken?).

I have values for such env variables like **AWS_SESSION_TOKEN, AWS_SECRET_KEY, AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN**. Maybe be they can be used for roleSessionName ?

**for V1 SDK**

```
AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Region.Global).build();

STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder stsBuilder = new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder(takenFromIAMRole, 
                                                roleSessionName??????????);
```

**for V2 SDK**

```
public S3Client s3Client(@Value(??????) String roleSessionName,  
        @Value(this is taken from IAM role) String role) {

 return S3Client
       .builder()
       .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
       .credentialsProvider(StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider
               .builder()
               .refreshRequest(() -> AssumeRoleRequest
                       .builder()
                       .roleArn(role)
                       .roleSessionName(roleSessionName)
                       .build())
               .build())
       .build();
```

Can anyone advice or direct where I can start to look for roleSessionName?